# KnockoutJS: dependency of two observables bidirectional

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bidirectional

the idea is very simple but I don't really know how to solve the following problem.

I want to calculate the periphery of a circle,

```
 U = 2*Math.PI*R
```

So, U is the periphery und R is the radius of the circle. The one-way-solution is easy. The HTML-code looks like

```
 R: <input data-bind="value: radius"><br>
 U: <input data-bind="value: periphery">
```

and the ViewModel looks like

```
 function ViewModel() {
    this.radius = ko.observable(1);
    this.periphery = ko.computed(function(){
       var r = parseFloat(this.radius());
       return 2*Math.PI*r;
    },this);
 }
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dundanox/2SsF9/

In this one-way-solution I type in a radius and get the periphery of the circle. Actually I simply could reverse the whole solution. Set the periphery and get the radius. But i intend to have a bi-directional-solution. How can I do this with KnockoutJS?

The next step is to fire an event when the circle (radius or periphery) has changed. Usually i would do a subscription:

```
 vm.radius.subscribe(function(r){ // do someting });
```

But, again, it is only a one-way-solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use writeable computed observables

```
this.periphery = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var r = parseFloat(this.radius());
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var p = parseFloat(value);
        var r = p / (2 * Math.PI)
        this.radius(r);
    },
    owner: this
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2qMJt/)**

Comment: OK, thanks, but this solution I tried already. Then the radius is something like a primary or "central" und periphery is a secondary observable. I have in mind a more decentralized solution. But in most cases I think the centralized version is very well. Here is an extended example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dundanox/6xP5m/7/)